# Change text in TextView every second

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement function like: press button and show in textView every 1 sec numbers from 1 to 10.

```
private void startCounting() {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            increaseNumber();
        }
    };

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);

}

private void increaseNumber() {
    number++;
    tvFragment.setText(number);
}
```

and I got `CalledFromWrongThreadException`
Ok, I know what is it, we cant update UI elements from background thread but question is how to fix it ? How to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Handler class.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private void startCounting() {
    handler.post(run);
}

private Runnable run = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    number++;
    tvFragment.setText(number);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
  }
};
```

Comment: how stop that counting now ?

Comment: To stop execution, call handler.removeCallbacks(handler);

Comment: handler.removeCallbacks(handler); gives an error. Is it handler.removeCallbacks(run);

Comment: `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` should work. From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable). You could also just stop it when it hits some number in the code, with `if( number < maxNum ) handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async task and in onPostExecute() method you can update the ui. Here is the tutorial you can refer:- https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial

Comment: asyncTask can be in loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CountDownTimer instead of Timer.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvText;
    private long totalTime = 10000, countDownInterval = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvText = findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    }

    public void startCounter(View view) {
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(totalTime, countDownInterval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvText.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tvText.setText("Your time is out.!");
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

and this is your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:onClick="startCounter"
        android:text="@string/start_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can get more info about countDownTimer from this link [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Answer (score 0):

Also simply you can use **runOnUiThread()** too.

You'd have to change your increaseNumber method like this:

```
private void increaseNumber() {
        number++;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFragment.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            }
        });

    }
```